# Python3 if something happens, don't do this part of code

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main():
     user = input('enter a user: ')
     data = ['john','gogo','baby','user']
     if user not in data:
         #stop the rest of the code
     print (user)
main()
```

Let's say the user enters "johnny" which is not in the list don't do (in my case) the while loop that is right after?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand you question. What about while loop?

Comment: @vaibhav Mule i fixed it

Comment: There is still no while loop. What exactly do you need to know?

Comment: @HelloWorld I have a program that uses a if statement. If something =! this: I want to send it to another function and do not continue this function?

Comment: @bob Do you know about `if`/`else`?

Comment: @leekaiinthesky lol of course I do know but its more complexe to do an if statement or whatever because after that statement, there is more code to be executed whatever happened in the if statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a return statement will end the function on that line.

```
def main():
  user = input('enter a user: ')
  data = ['john','gogo','baby','user']
  if user not in data:
    #stop the rest of the code 
    return
  print (user)

main()
```

Comment: I see your comment that you want to 'send it to another function'. You can write another function and call it before 'return'. If that doesn't make sense, you may want to do some Python/programming tutorials.

Comment: I know how to send it to another function but I was wondering if i could use the break statement to stop it if its not in it instead of return?

Comment: break statements are used when you have a loop. You're not using a loop here so break statement isn't the right thing to use. What are you trying to do that makes you think you need a break statement? Do you need to get back to main()? In that case just omit the return statement and it will continue executing main after your other function returns.

Comment: I want to stop that function totally so it doesn't run at all

Comment: OK - to end the main() function right away return will work fine. FYI, it seems like you thought break would end the whole function - it will only end the loop it's in, so the rest of the function would still run. http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ is a good resource for learning how to program in Python if you want to dig deeper.

Answer (score 1):

You can approach it this the other way:

```
if user in data:
```

Then you can put your code after this `if statement` and the code will only be executed if `user` is in `data`.